# Salt: Using salt state in jinja if-else state

Tags: jinja2, salt-stack

I'm trying to deploy a django project with saltstack.

I wrote a sls file and It installs packages and run some commands.

It installs django, nginx, etc and I want to run `manage.py collectstatic` for nginx.

but when I re-apply this formula, It returns an error that /static directory is already exists.

so I modified the sls file

```
collect_static_files:
{% if not salt['file.exists'][BASEDIR,'myproject/static']|join('') %}
  cmd.run:
    - name: '~~~ collectstatic;'
    - cwd: /path/to/venv/bin
{% else %}
  cmd.run:
    - name: echo "Static directory exists."
{% endif %}
```

but when I run `salt '*' state.apply myformula`,

It says:

```
minion:
 Data failed to compile:
----------
    Rendering SLS 'base:myproj' failed: Jinja variable 'salt.utils.templates.AliasedLoader object' has no attribute 'file.exists'
```

How can I solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was a fool...
`{% if not salt['file.directory_exists'](BASEDIR + 'myproject/static') %}`
worked well.
The problem was I used the state module not execution module of salt.
Now I understand that state module describes "state" and execution modules act like a function.